# How to enable and accept HTTPS connections and setup SSL certificates on GCE

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Compute Engine, I have a VM instance with wordpress installed.

I want to enable HTTPS, I have cloudflare ssl for the domain, but as soon as I turned on ssl in wordpress (setting siteurl to https://domain.com) it fudges up and wont load any longer.

Ive tried looking very hard through Google cloud documentation, cant find anything that helps.

All I want is to install an SSL cert on my instance, allow https connection through and get on with setting up the rest of my site!

But it seems there is no way to do this?
ANy help will be greatly appreciated,
thankyou

Comment: This is not related to GCE or programming. Configuring an HTTP server for SSL hardly has anything to do with the platform hosting the server. Check [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) or the documentation for the web server you are using to configure SSL and HTTPS support.

Comment: Yes it is related to GCE, how do i access all of the innards of my instance to tinker with these things?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue @Breakhty, I'm reaching out to a friend to help me and will post steps as soon as I hear back. Somehow I got it working on another instance but forgot how I did it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set "Allow HTTPS traffic" on VM Instance's settings page